# Urls not working while integrating custom application with django-cms

Tags: django, django-models, django-cms

I'm trying to integrate an django application with django-cms. I'm using the basic "Poll" application as mentioned in basic Django tutorial and following guidelines over [here](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-cms/en/2.1.3/extending_cms/extending_examples.html#my-first-app-apphook).

Now I can integrate the application and can view the "poll" page. But when I press 'submit', the django-cms gives me error

**"CMS: Page not found for "polls/1/vote"**

Update: If I add following line to main urls.py, everything works fine.

```
(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
```

But this is usually discouraged in django and django-cms. Is there a way out?

Comment: why is it discouraged to add "routes" in django and/or django-cms ?

Comment: @poelinca - Because this means that the app is not easily portable, since it requires changing the urls.py manually. Ideally the app should latch automatically.

Comment: if you use django.contrib.admin app you still need to edit both settings.py and urls.py right ? so why should polls.py act diferently ? look at urls.py as a config file too ( like settings.py ) . ps: this comes from a php perspective i've played with django only a few hours .

Comment: The point of being portable wrt to django-cms is, that if an app works on say /polls/, you should be able to change it to, say, /new-polls/, without manually editing the urls file. Using django-cms you can do that by creating apphooks and attaching these apphooks to pages.

Comment: admin app is a special case and is required only once for every django  installation. You may need to add hundreds of apps and that would lead to a very very cluttered urls.py. So ideally, you should only add your app in INSTALLED_APPS settings, and that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh, I figured it out. Well the hard-coded URLs inside the app templates do not work. One should use {% url %} tags inside the templates.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is create an apphook for your polls application and include the urls there. Have a look at: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.1.3/extending_cms/extending_examples.html#my-first-app-apphook

**EDIT**

Remember to restart the server once you attach the apphook.

Comment: thats exactly what I'm following at the moment. But following this only leads me to the voting page, so atleast some of the urls are working as mentioned in the article. But when I press 'submit' on voting page, the form has action pointed to `/polls/id/vote`. And this particular URL is not available unless I add manual URL path in urls.py.:(

Comment: If you mean that you are adding an entry for /polls/id/vote in polls.urls (ie the urls file for the polls app), then this is fine, ie, must have been a mistake in the documentation.

Comment: There is the django-cms users mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/django-cms

Comment: I've answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Using apphooks would be the solution, however It works if you put the cms url route at last, at the end of the urlpatterns. Try that